# Sorting Dictionarys in Arrays

Tags: xcode, swift

I have some dictionarys and I want to sort them into arrays based on their price float.

```
   // what I have
        product1 = ["name": "milk","price": 3.2]
        product2 = ["name": "bread","price": 2.9] 
        product3 = ["name": "meat","price": 4.1] 
        product4 = ["name": "sweets", "price": 1.0]
// what I want to convert it to
        priceArray = [1.0,2.9,3.2,4.1] 
        nameArray = ["sweets","bread","milk","meat"]
```

I want to make it so that the cheapest product is first in both the priceArray and the nameArray, and have all the products sorted like that

Comment: what *exactly* is the input? Are you really having multiple `productX` variables? Is the expected output 2 different arrays which are ordered in the same way? What have *you* tried so far?

Comment: Why won't you store your product data as a class/struct in the first place? Then you can put them in the array and sort them by price.

Comment: I am using parse and downloading a number of dictionaries, and I want to sort them based on their price. So that nameArray[0] is equal to the cheapest product, and priceArray[0] is the price of that product

Comment: You should do what @SebastianOsiński suggested. Use a class/struct to store the data - you **DO NOT** want to split the different data points of one data set across different arrays.

Comment: yeah ok, how do you store the data as a class/struct?

Comment: You have to define Product struct/class with properties name and price. Then you can initialize instances of this class with name and price taken from your dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it this way:

```
let product1 = ["name": "milk","price": 3.2]
let product2 = ["name": "bread","price": 2.9]
let product3 = ["name": "meat","price": 4.1]
let product4 = ["name": "sweets", "price": 1.0]

var tempDictArray = [[String: AnyObject]]()
tempDictArray.append(product1)
tempDictArray.append(product2)
tempDictArray.append(product3)
tempDictArray.append(product4)

func priceSort(dict1: [String: AnyObject], dict2: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    let price1 = dict1["price"] as? Float ?? 0
    let price2 = dict2["price"] as? Float ?? 0
    return price1 < price2
}


tempDictArray = tempDictArray.sort(priceSort)

var priceArray = [Float]()
var nameArray = [String]()

for item in tempDictArray {

    let price = item["price"] as! Float
    let name = item["name"] as! String

    priceArray.append(price)
    nameArray.append(name)
}
priceArray    //[1, 2.9, 3.2, 4.1]
nameArray     //["sweets", "bread", "milk", "meat"]
```

Answer (score 2):

### 1. The model

First of all let's use a struct to represent the data, it will make thing much clearer and safer than using `Dictionaries`.

```
struct Product {
    let name: String
    let price: Double

    init?(dict:[String:Any]) {
        guard
            let name = dict["name"] as? String,
            let price = dict["price"] as? Double else {
                return nil
            }
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }
}
```

### 2. The input

Now given this input

```
let product1: [String: Any] = ["name": "milk","price": 3.2]
let product2: [String: Any] = ["name": "bread","price": 2.9]
let product3: [String: Any]  = ["name": "meat","price": 4.1]
let product4: [String: Any]  = ["name": "sweets", "price": 1.0]
```

we just put the 4 dictionaries inside an Array

```
let productsDict = [product1, product2, product3, product4]
```

then we transform the array of dictionaries into an array od `Product(s)` sorted by `price`

### 3. A sorted array of Product(s)

```
let products = productsDict.flatMap { Product(dict: $0) }.sort{ $0.price < $1.price }
```

### 4. Extracting the price and the name

Finally we transform it into an array of `Double` populated with the `price` property

```
let prices = products.map { $0.price }
```

And into an array of `String` populated with the `name` property.

```
let names = products.map { $0.name }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let product1 = ["name": "milk","price": 3.2]
let product2 = ["name": "bread","price": 2.9]
let product3 = ["name": "meat","price": 4.1]
let product4 = ["name": "sweets", "price": 1.0]

// Define a structure to hold your data.
// The protocol CustomStringConvertible allows you to format the
// data as a nice string for printing.

struct Product: CustomStringConvertible {
    var name: String
    var price: Double
    var description: String { return "name: \(name), price: \(price)" }

    init?(info: [String: NSObject]) {
        guard let name = info["name"] as? String,
              let price = info["price"] as? Double else { return nil }
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }
}

// Create an array of your products initializing them with the dictionary
// values.  Since the initializer for Product is failable (might return
// nil), here we use flatMap to get rid of any ones that failed to init.    
var products = [Product(info: product1), Product(info: product2), Product(info: product3), Product(info: product4)].flatMap {$0}

// Now it is easy to sort your product array on price.    
products.sortInPlace { $0.price < $1.price }

// Print out the products in order to show that they are sorted.    
products.forEach { print($0) }

// Use map to create the priceArray and nameArray from [products]
let priceArray = products.map { $0.price }  // [1.0, 2.9, 3.2, 4.1]
let nameArray = products.map { $0.name }    // ["sweets", "bread", "milk", "meat"]
```

Output:

> ```
> name: sweets, price: 1.0
> name: bread, price: 2.9
> name: milk, price: 3.2
> name: meat, price: 4.1
> ```

Comment: Yes, @appzYourLife, remarkably similar.  That should give OP confidence in the answers.